# Drupal 8 getting empty $_GET variable

Tags: drupal-8

i'm working with Drupal 8, and i'm trying to receive a get variable called id, the url looks like http://localhost/drp/listado/editar/2.

this is the function in the controller

```
public function edit(Request $request){

    $id = $request->query->get('id');
    $conexion = \Drupal::database();
    $query = $conexion->query("Select * from node where nid = ".$id);
    $result = $query->fetchAll();

  return array(
      '#id' => $id,
      '#datos' => $result,
      '#theme' => 'editar',
      '#titulo' => 'Editar'
      );

  }
```

but i get this error in reports/dblogs

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: Select * from node where nid =;
```

this is the custom_controller.routing.yml

```
custom_controller.editar:
  path: '/listado/editar/{id}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_controller\Controller\ListController::edit'
    _title: 'Edit'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access_content'
```

it's not getting the value of the variable, any help is welcome, thanks

Comment: Whats your route definition? Are you sure `id` is getting bound to the last part of the URL? Also, you're prone to SQL injection attacks by dropping the raw ID value into your query. Look into query and bind parameters.

Comment: i updated the post, i added the routing.yml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first parameter your controller is receiving is `id`, the second parameter is request which is automatic. See here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/using-parameters-in-routes

Maybe you can print the contents of the first parameter and `die()` to check what value Drupal is passing.

Comment: thanks man, it was that, i thought the request array would contain the get id

Answer (score 1):

Install devel module first and dump `$request` variable. After hitting url you can get id Parameter.

Comment: thanks mate, this issue is actually solved, but i will install the devel module if it helps me to get clear answers for the errors